# navigationController = null in TableViewController's pushViewController method (popover)

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, popover

First of all, sorry for my English. 
I'm trying to do an app for iPad with a navigation controller which pushes view controllers when a button "Next" is selected. But I also want to have a popover, called from a button in the nav bar, that allows the user to "jump" from one view controller to another, pushing it with the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and the pushViewController:animated: methods, but it's not working.

Summary:

**Tab bar** -> switches between FirstViewController and SecondViewController (**works just fine**)

**Nav bar (button Next)** -> switches between SecondViewController, FirstSlideController and SecondSlideController (**it's also good**)

**Popover** -> user selects SecondViewController, FirstSlideController or SecondSlideController (**here's the problem!**)

Codes:

**AppDelegate**

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1, navigationController2];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

**TableViewController(popover)'s didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row == 0){
 FirstSlideController *detailViewController = [[FirstSlideController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstSlideController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

else if(indexPath.row == 1){
    SecondSlideController *detailViewController = [[SecondSlideController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondSlideController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
else{
    SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

}

**SecondViewController (with delegate suggested by maros)**

```
-(void) showPopover:(id) sender
{
   TableViewController *PopoverView = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
   self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopoverView];
   self.popOver.delegate = self;
   [self.popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated: YES];
}
```

I tried to print self.navigationController and it says it's null. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Presnented UIPopoverController is not pushed on the navigation stack in the view controller from which it was presented. It is a separate view controller. 
Therefore the navigationController inside the popover is nil.

What I would recommend you is to create a delegate **MyNavigationPopoverDelegate** (the class that creates a popover (**PopoverController**). Pass it's instance as an delegate to the **TableViewController**.

After users clicks on some button inside popover, call delegate's method to processes button clicks (**myNavigationPopover:(UIPopoverController*)popover clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex**).

Then maybe dismiss delegate?

and finally change navigation however you want! :)

```
@protocol MyNavigationPopoverDelegate
- (void) myNavigationPopover:(UIPopoverController*)popover clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
@end

@interface TableViewController : UITableVieController // your viewController in popover
... // your code
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject <MyNavigationPopoverDelegate> * delegate;
... // your code
@end

@implementation TableViewController
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate myNavigationPopover:self clickedButtonAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
...
@end

// defines that SecondViewController implements the delegate's method
@interface SecondViewController <MyNavigationPopoverDelegate> : UIViewController 
  // your code
@end

// code where you presenting popover 
@implementation SecondViewController

// This is the method that is executed after your button press and it is responsible for presenting a popover
- (void) presentPopover{
   ...
   myPopover.delegate = self; // setting the delegate
   [myPopover presentPopoverFromXXX ...]; // however you present it
   ...
}

 - (void) myNavigationPopover:(UIPopoverController*)popover clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
 UINavigationController *currentNavigationController = ; // get the navigation controller from the tab bar

 if(buttonIndex == 0){
      FirstSlideController *detailViewController = [[FirstSlideController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstSlideController" bundle:nil];
      [currentNavigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 }

 else if(buttonIndex == 1){
      SecondSlideController *detailViewController = [[SecondSlideController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondSlideController" bundle:nil];
      [currentNavigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 }
 else{
      SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
      [currentNavigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 }
}

@end;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use delegate, but I tried and it says there's an error at     [self.delegate myNavigationPopover:self clickedButtonAtIndex:indexPath.row];   It says there isn't a property called delegate at TableViewController class

Comment: By the way, I put the implementation of the delegate at TableViewController.h, that's right ? Thank you! :)

Comment: @user2303633 Some tutorial will help you e.g. [link](http://ios-objectivec-tutorials.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/delegates-in-objective-c.html). You should first define the delegate as a property on PopoverController, then you can pass the instance there. The implementation of the delegate should be done on the class from which you create the PopoverController.

Comment: See, I have a method in the SecondViewController where I implement the method of pressing the button of the popover, which initializes the popover with the content of a TableViewController object (I put this method in the question now). So how can I do this part    "myPopover.delegate = self; // setting the delegate" ? Because the delegate hasn't a myPopover property...

Comment: And thanks for the tutorial... I read it but I still didn't get it =/

Comment: I have just edit my answer. Look for `SecondViewController` in the code.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working... I put the protocol at TableViewCobtroller.h, since there is where we're going to delegate methods, but then SecondViewController doesn't find MyNavigationPopoverDelegate. and also myPopover.delegate = self receives a warning message because are assigning two different types (UIPopoverControllerDelegate and SecondViewController). It's probably some mistake I made... thanks again

Comment: Just solved the problem of not finding protocol... Now there's no errors but it doesn't works either.

Comment: @user2303633 Implementation of the protocol should be definitely on the SecondViewController. Check: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)